# UILoader does not act as MovieClip for Drag and drop; How can you make UILoader to behave like MovieClip

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I wrote this code below counselors I saw here
Its main goal is to import images from xml to the main stage and then play with them with the "Drag and drop Function"

When I turn it on everything is fine,
But when I click on the pictures to the "Drag and drop Function"
I get this message

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert fl.containers::UILoader@1a52f1f1 to flash.display.MovieClip.
    at forgallery_fla::MainTimeline/item_onMouseDown()
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert fl.containers::UILoader@1a52f1f1 to flash.display.MovieClip.
    at forgallery_fla::MainTimeline/item_onMouseUp()
```

How to fix the problem and make UILoader to UILoader

```
import fl.containers.UILoader;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var count:Number = 0;
//Requires:
// UILoader control in Library

var xmlLoader:URLLoader= new URLLoader();
var myXML:XML = new XML  ;
var uiLoader:UILoader= new UILoader();

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("Gallery.xml"));

function loadXML(e:Event):void
{
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML)
    for(var i:int = 0; i <2; i++)
    { 
    root["pic"+i].source = myXML.pic[i];
    }
} 

var dragArray:Array = [pic0, pic1];

for(var i:int = 0; i < dragArray.length; i++)
{
    dragArray[i].buttonMode = true;
    dragArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
    dragArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, item_onMouseUp);
}

function item_onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var clip:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);
    addChild(clip); //bring to the front
    clip.startDrag();
}
function item_onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var clip:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);
    clip.stopDrag();
}
```

THE XML TREE IS

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Gallery height="300" width="300" >
    <pic>p1.jpg</pic>
    <pic>p2.jpg</pic>
    <pic>p3.jpg</pic>


</Gallery>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to cast your `UILoader` as a `MovieClip`. `startDrag` is a method of `Sprite`. `UILoader` is a `Sprite`, not a `MovieClip`.

```
function item_onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var clip:Sprite = Sprite(event.currentTarget);
    addChild(clip); //bring to the front
    clip.startDrag();
}
```

You could have found this out in the [`UILoader` reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/containers/UILoader.html#methodSummary).